# How to insert the excel data to database?In console application

Tags: c#, .net

In this way we have to insert the value by first 3 column insert first row and 2nd 3 column insert next row.this is the logic.
[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPu6z.png)
in ths image the corporate id is same for all the companies, 1st two colunm insert 1st row in database table, next 2 colunm insert into next row in table.

using sqlbulkcopy insert the data in 1st row but i have this way( the corporate id is same for all the companies, 1st two colunm insert 1st row in database table, next 2 colunm insert into next row in table.)

Comment: Use ClosedXML - https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML